# Copy parts from several attribute tables in shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, spatial-join

I have several shapefiles from which I wish to take parts from their attributes tables to make a new attributes table.

Is this possible without destroying the original attributes table? I have features connected to them.

If I were to use the join tool, how do I join from several layers?

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to copy attributes or features? Have you looked into joins?

Comment: The attributes. Haven't actually tried join on this one. But I've tried it earlier it other projects, didn't got it to work. 
If i join two tables to make a new one then, that will not cause problems with the attribute tables that I'm joining from? I mean, i have features connected to those.

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to improve it with responses to any requests for clarifications that appear in comments.  A description of how the parts of a question interrelate is at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question/3353#3353

Comment: By "take parts from their attribute tables", do you mean to take a subset of fields from the shapefile's attribute table off into a separate standalone table?

Comment: A join does not modify the contents of the original tables on its own, it only establishes a data _relationship_.

Comment: PolyGeo 
Yes that what i mean, i want to make a new shapefile/attribut table from my several tables that i allready have, but i just to have some of the data from it, not all.